# Using Julia ifelse with an array

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia 1.0.3 and I'm attempting to run a line of code that was written in Julia 0.7. This line runs the base ifelse function along an array of boolean values. It appears that in this version of Julia, the ifelse function can no longer be run against a bitarray. Is there a way to get ifelse to work here?

```
x = collect(0:0.1:2) 
x2 = ifelse(2 .- 2*x.>=0, 2 .- 2*x, 0)
```

I'm expecting to get an array that shows 2-2x for all values of x>=0 and 0 otherwise. I am getting the following error.

```
TypeError: non-boolean (BitArray{1}) used in boolean context

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[67]:1
```

Comment: This code was likely written in Julia 0.5 or earlier — it was deprecated in Julia 0.6.  If you run it there, Julia will happily give you the answer with a deprecation warning: `WARNING: ifelse(c::AbstractArray{Bool}, x::AbstractArray, y) is deprecated, use ifelse.(c, x, y) instead.`  When updating code, it can be very helpful to walk through each version and fix the deprecation warnings as you go.

Comment: BTW, there is no reason to use `collect`. Just use the range `0:0.1:2` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put a dot `.` after `ifelse` to broadcast. Many functions that operates on elements of collections require broadcasting with dot syntax on Julia 1.x.

```
x = collect(0:0.1:2) 
x2 = ifelse.(2 .- 2*x.>=0, 2 .- 2*x, 0.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides what others have mentioned, your code suffers from type instability problem. Use `@code_warntype` to verify this. `x` has elements of type `Float64` and inside `ifelse` you have one branch with type `Float64` and the other with type `Int64`. This can be solved by using `zero(eltype(x))` instead of `0`.

Instead of this strange condition `2 - 2*x >= 0`, use this equivalent simple one `x <= 1`. Also, instead of broadcasting, I suggest using `map` which is faster and doesn't allocate. See below.

```
x = 0:0.1:2
x2 = map(x -> ifelse(x <= 1, 2 - 2x, zero(eltype(x))), x)
```