# Compare array values with a value in Julia

Tags: julia

I have an array `a = [1, 2, 3, 4];`. I want to compare each element of array a with a number and return a new array contains True/False elements **in Julia as few steps as possible**. I try `result = a < 2` and expected array is `result = [True, False, False, False]` but it's not working. Hope your help

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54204198/using-julia-ifelse-with-an-array/54204376

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to vectorize (broadcast) the comparison operator so it operates on `Vector`s.
You can do this by adding a dot `.` to your code.

```
julia> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
4-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> a .<= 2
4-element BitVector:
 1
 1
 0
 0
```

Read more about broadcasting [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Broadcast-and-vectorization).

Note that Python's numpy will do this for you automatically, but there are cases where an operation might be ambiguous - do you want it to be element wise or a matrix multiplication? So Julia solves this by explicitly broadcasting any operation with the `.` command.